# Java: Nested if statement

Tags: java

I have an if statement that validate the input of user. For example, there are 2 things that I would like to validate. First is whether all the textfield is empty. If one of the textfield is no filled in, a pop up appear. Second is whether password and confirm password is the same. When password and confirm password is not the same, a pop up appear. The problem is when both condition met, two pop up appear continuously. What I like to do is when both of the scenario happens, the nested if will not trigger instead only the main if will trigger. The nested if will trigger only when all of the textfield are filled and password and confirm password are not matched.

```
if(TextField1.getText().isEmpty()||TextField2.getText().isEmpty()||TextField2.getText().isEmpty()
            ||TextField4.getText().isEmpty()||TextField5.getText().isEmpty()||TextField6.getText().isEmpty()
            ||TextField8.getText().isEmpty()||TextField9.getText().isEmpty()||TextField10.getText().isEmpty()){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please fill in all the details!",
        "Invalid Input", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        if(!TextField4.getText().equals(TextField5.getText())){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Password and Confirm Password is not the same!",
        "Invalid Input", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
    }else{
           writetoFile();
}
```

Comment: Make the second `if` an `else if` and move it outside the first `if`.

Comment: Consider adding the textfields to an array, and iterate through that array to find if any of them needs all the details. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Comment: You could replace all of the empty checks with a stream: `Stream.of(textField1, textField2, ...).map(f -> f.getText()).findAny().isPresent()`. Or put the text fields into an array or list and create the stream using `Arrays.stream(array)` or `list.stream()` respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need an if-ifelse-else condition here.
Try something like this (code untested)

```
if(TextField1.getText().isEmpty()||TextField2.getText().isEmpty()||TextField2.getText().isEmpty()
            ||TextField4.getText().isEmpty()||TextField5.getText().isEmpty()||TextField6.getText().isEmpty()
            ||TextField8.getText().isEmpty()||TextField9.getText().isEmpty()||TextField10.getText().isEmpty()){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please fill in all the details!",
        "Invalid Input", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
} else if(!TextField4.getText().equals(TextField5.getText())){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Password and Confirm Password is not the same!",
        "Invalid Input", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }else{
           writetoFile();
}
```

Comment: oh yes, I forgot this option.

Answer (score 1):

After Triggering the first popup use `return;` then it wont go to the second validation.

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please fill in all the details!",
    "Invalid Input", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
return;
```